# Plone upgrade from 4.1 to 4.2 - Comments not working, and a folder missing from Navigation

Tags: plone

We upgraded our Plone from 4.1.3 to 4.2 recently.

After the upgrading, we are not able to add comments anymore.  That is, there is no Add Comments anymore after we select Allow comments for a folder, etc.

Also, we have a folder called News containing our news items.  In the folder, we have a collection also called News.    The News folder tab used to appear in the navigation bar, i.e., we didn't select "Exclude from navigation" in the News folder settings.

After the upgrade, we saw a Collections (old style) in the Site Setup.  We went to ZMI's portal_types/Topic/manage_propertiesForm and then hit Save without changing any setting.  That is, ZMI -> portal_types -> Topic (Collection).  There is no Topic (collection old style) as mentioned in the Upgrading Plone 4.1 to 4.2 guide. Immediately after that, the News folder tab disappeared from the navigation, and we are not able to bring it back again.  Could this be caused by our using Collection for our news items?

Comment: What kind of comments are you trying to migrate if they are not "old" Plone comments? Are you using any commenting add-on product?

Comment: Hi tisto, thank you for the response.  we just found out that actually all the news comments have been migrated.  there is a mistake in the screen out from plone comments migrate.  the problem we have now is Comments is not possible now.  there is no more Add Comments anymore even if Allow Comments is checked.  Also, the News tab is missing from Navigation.

Comment: Check if the commenting viewlet shows up. If you have a custom theme it might not be included.

Comment: Hi Tisto.   Thank you for the response once again. I don't know a commenting viewlet is.   But the Add comment at the bottom of an article no longer appears.   And in articles with old comments, there is a line at the bottom: Commenting has been disabled.   And we had enabled commenting.   No, we do not have a custom theme.   We are using Plone default theme.

Comment: Hi Tisto.  Could this be caused by the old style collection we used for our News items in our News folder?   This is because our News folder disappeared after we clicked Save in ZMI -> portal_types -> Topic (Collection).  Also, there is mention about a new plone.app.collection 1.0.4 in Plone 4.2.   I tried to delete out News collection but was unable to find the collection in the contents folder to delete.  It seems that the News collection is still effective but nowhere to be found --- maybe because it is old-style, it isn't upgraded properly during the upgrade from 4.1.3 to 4.2.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tisto, okay we figured out the Add Comments problem.  After we went to Site Setup -> Discussion and then select Globally Enable Comments, the Add Comments started working.   Now, the problem of the missing News tab in the navigation is still unresolved.  Probably caused by the old-style collection being used.

Answer (score 0):

We kind of resolved our issue.   To make Commenting possible again, have to go to Site setup -> Discussions and select Globally Enable Comments.

To make our News folder appear in the navigation, we had to change the short name of the folder (the url name) from news to something else, and then the News folder reappeared in the top navigation bar again.   Don't know why.  Maybe some name conflict because of the upgrade or the new style collection?   We are still using the old style collection because the new style collection has a bug -- it still list 30 items per page even though the limit of max search results to set to something lower.   in the old style collection, if we limit the max search results to say 5, then only 5 items will be displayed per page.  yes max search results is a misnomer.    i think this is a bug and will be submitting it to plone dve.

we now have another problem.  when we set the news folder as the default page of our site, when users go to our site, the Add New button is not there.   but when the user clicks on the News tab in navigation, the Add New button is there (for the user to add news item).  So there is a different between the default_page setting in ZMI site property and the News tab in navigation.

Thank you

Comment: please accept your answer, so we can sort questions by 'answered' and 'not answered', thanks in advance. also the last paragraph could be deleted, as it's a new question.